# PHP: Read from File and Count

Tags: php, nagios

i am struggling with this:

I'd like to parse the nagios.dat file with php, looking for each line:

**"problem_has_been_acknowledged=X"** and count how often the value behind is 1.

Comment: `dat` files tend to be binary - what format are the ones you are trying to read and process?

Comment: The file is plain text... Nagios just call it a .dat file

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = "/test.dat";
$string = "problem_has_been_acknowledged=1";
$count = substr_count(file_get_contents($file), $string);

echo $count;
```

Comment: Nice solution but it will fail if the values can be larger than 9 (10, 100, etc.).

Comment: Why will it fail?

Comment: Because it will count `problem_has_been_acknowledged=15` as well. Not a problem if it's just `1`'s and `0`'s of course but that's not entirely clear from the question.

Comment: I see. You could set length as parameter.

Comment: It was just a comment in case anybody finds this answer. For the OP it should work fine, based on the name of the variable.

Comment: @Kjellson The original solution should work fine, see for example here: https://eval.in/645446

Comment: @Michael I hope you don't mind but I rolled-back your edit as that would cause it to stop working.

Comment: to avoid 10, 15, 100 check for carrier return ? `"problem_has_been_acknowledged=1\n";`